# Making individual letters in a string different colours

Tags: javascript, string, function

I'm trying to make the colour different for certain letters (if found) in a string eg. the letter i. The search count is working I just can't figure out the changing html colour of the individual letter.

I know if it was a whole word then I could just use split strings, but can't figure out how to do it for a single letter. I've found some examples, one that I have tried is at the bottom that is not working either.

```
//getMsg is another function, which passes in a user inputted string
function searchMsg(getMsg) { 
            alert (getMsg);
            var msgBoxObject = document.getElementById('msgBox');
            var pos = getMsg.indexOf('i')
            var txtToFind = (document.getElementById('txtToFind').value);
            var count = 0;

            while (pos !== -1){
                count++;
                pos = getMsg.indexOf('i', pos + 1);

                document.writeln (+count);

            msgBoxObject.innerHTML = (count);
        }

    getMsg = getMsg.replace('/i/g<span class="red">i</span>');
 document.writeln (getMsg);

}


 Edit; I've added in this, but can't get the loop to work correctly so it displays all instances of the letter found instead of just one: /*while (pos !== -1){
                count++;
                pos = getMsg.indexOf('i', pos + 1);

                document.writeln (+count);

            msgBoxObject.innerHTML = (count);
        }
        */
```

var count = 0; // Count of target value
    var i = 0;     // Iterative counter

```
// Examine each element.
for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++) 
{   if(arr[i] == targetValue) 
        count++;
}
return count;
}

searchIndex = txtMsg.indexOf(txtToFind);
        if (searchIndex >=0 ) {
      // Copy text from phrase up till the match.
      matchPhrase = txtMsg.slice(0, searchIndex);
      matchPhrase += '<font color="red">' + txtToFind + '</font>';
      matchPhrase += txtMsg.slice(searchIndex + txtToFind.length);          
} else {
      matchPhrase = "No matches"
}

displayProcessedMsg(matchPhrase);
```

document.writeln(matchPhrase);

Comment: do you have a piece of css with the style change for that class: `('/i/g<span class="red">i</span>');`

Comment: you will need to wrap by a span tag with style="color:yourcolor"

Comment: I don't have a piece of css with that class, I just adapted it from a similar example, was just trying a few things. John, not sure which part you mean I should wrap?

Comment: jsfiddle update, can still only output one instance of the colour  http://jsfiddle.net/106rdqg1/1/

Answer (score 1):

You either need to add the corresponding css for that class or change the tag like @john_Smith specified

**Adding the CSS**

```
span.red {
  color: red;
}
```

**Changing the tag**

On your code replace this

```
getMsg = getMsg.replace('/i/g<span class="red">i</span>');
```

for

```
getMsg = getMsg.replace('/i/g<span style:"color:red">i</span>');
```

[Some example of inline css](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/css/examples/cssinline.htm)

**Some advice on color palettes**

Try looking into [d3](/questions/tagged/d3) color scales(https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#categorical-colors) or apply a principle similar to incrementing an RGB value instead of using names of colors.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I've adapted the message, only using html though, but can't get the loop to work correctly so that it colours all instances of the letter/ word found not just one: